# Misunderstanding on how reactJS properties work

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to understand how properties work in reactJS and was trying to complete a tic tac toe game to help me accomplish this. Here's a block of code that confused me:

```
class Board extends React.Component 
{
  renderSquare(i) 
  {
    return <Square value={i} />;
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Square extends React.Component 
{
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

What I don't understand: The parent component, board, returns the child component square with a value of i. So how does Board pass the property to the child class square? I am a total noob so its possible I'm completely wrong about my understanding of this somewhere.

Comment: It's showing you right there in the code. `<Square value={i} />` using a property called `value`, with the value `i` that you passed into the function that generates the Square component. In you want to properly understand React, head over to the react website and take their tutorial, which is _really good_ and is well worth your half hour to an hour to get a solid understanding of how everything works. Code along, and you'll be happy you did.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Functions don't have child components. Instead, that function _builds_ a component (and not a child component, just "a component"). In this case a `<Square>` with Square's property `value` set to some value, and any property set on any component can be access _by that component_ using `this.props.propertyname`. So, because you're creating `<Square value={i}/>`, the Square component can access the `value` property through `this.props.value` in its own code. Which you can see it doing in the code for Square's `render()` function.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans my brain wasn't looking at it correctly. I think I get it now. the return statement calls the "render square" function 9 times to assign each square in the rows a value, right?

Comment: exactly. The board's `render` ends up building nine `Square` components.

Comment: what does the keyword "this" refer to when the function returns this.renderSquare(0)? Is the this referring to the component board or the component square? I don't know how it would be referring to square if the square isn't created until the function itself is called

Comment: `this` in JS is scoped to execution context, or declaration context if you're using arrow functions. Inside board's render function, `this` is "the specific board instance". Instead square's render function, `this` is "the specific square instance". There are a bunch of great answers to how `this` works in JS on Stackoverflow though, look them up and given them a read-through.

Answer (score 0):

This function return a JSX expression with a Square component that accepts a prop called value with a value i.

```
renderSquare(i) 
 {
   return <Square value={i} />;
 }
```

So you are calling that function from Board's render method and passing as argument the i parameter.
In your case it will render 3 blocks of 3 squares each one with i value parameter that i think could be used to calculate the Width x Height of the square.

**Note:** What you need to understand here is that props are passed from parent components to child components and consumed by them via this.props.nameOfTheProp or just using destructuring from ES6 like this:

```
const { nameOfTheProp } = this.props;
```

In this case inside Square component, in some part of the code maybe inside a function called calculateArea or even in the same render method the prop called value is being used like this:

```
   render() {
     const { value } = this.props;
      return (
      <canvas
        id="mySquare"
        width={value * 50}
        height={value * 50}
        style={{ border: "1px solid #d3d3d3" }}
      >
        Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
      </canvas>
    );
   }
```

Then if you in Board render method pass to renderSquare(i=1) square will 
receive it and render a canvas with 1 * 50 width and height.

Comment: What I don't understand is how exactly props are passed from parent components to child components. For example, how does the Square class have any connection to the Board class? how does this.props.value work? There is no function for the value variable to be passed to. How do the "this" keywords know what to reference?

Comment: Think of it like the [DOM tree](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/DOM-model.svg/1200px-DOM-model.svg.png). You have a parent node that have child nodes (childrens/components rendered inside the parent). So the conection is established when Board render the component Square in its render method and the props are create in that conection you can manually send it via, in this case <Square **value=**> or using High Order Components like connect from Redux with mapStateToProps().